# How to search a directory for a file type of unknown name

Tags: c#, search, directory

I am running a routine which uses a `switch` case to complete a series of commands. One step is to await a .csv text file, with an unknown file name, to be produced by another program and to execute some analysis.

I've seen suggestions for using a `FileSystemWatcher` but this relies on using handles where I am already in the middle of a routine.

```
Switch (command)
{
  case "WAIT":
   {
     while(bool found = false)
     {
       if(//NEW .csv file in a known directory exists)
          {
            found = true;
          }
       Thread.Sleep(100);
     }
     //do some stuff with the .csv file.
     break;
   }

}
```

Simply put, when a new .csv file is found in the directory, it will be checked and move to the next step of the routine.

Comment: Are you just asking how to read a directory in C#?  `Directory.GetFiles` ?

Comment: @David, No, i am asking how I can see if there any new files in a directory, and if they are new and .csv to then do something with them. I am not aware how I can do this with `Directory.GetFiles`

Comment: @MJ2507 - Couldn't you use `Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\path to search", "*.csv");` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for any created `csv` file in your directory using a `FileSystemWatcher`. Instead of your `while` loop, use this:

```
using (var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(directoryPath, "*.csv"))
{
     watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
     var watcherCreatedFile = watcher.WaitForChanged(WatcherChangeTypes.Created); 
    //this will wait for a file to be created

    if (watcherCreatedFile.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
    {
        //will trigger when a file is created
        string fileNameCreated = watcherCreatedFile.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @FF - Thanks for this - there may be other .csv files in this directory so this could return an 'old' file. I specifically need to wait until a .csv file is present where it was not beforehand.

Comment: In that case, ganchito55's answer is closer to what you need. I'm updating my anwser with my approach using ```FileSystemWatcher```

Comment: @MJ2507 I updated my answer, check if it does what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what are you asking for. However maybe a method like that should be ok:

```
public void ProcessCsvFile(){
    using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
    {
        watcher.Path = args[1];         

        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

        // Add event handlers.     
        watcher.Created += (source,e)=>ProcessImportFile(e.FullPath);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for the file");
        Console.Read();
    }    
}
```

You have to create the filesystemwatcher and a handler to manage the created event that is going to be raised when someone puts the file in that folder.

Comment: thanks for the comment - i will be in the middle of a routine so I cannot use a handler (as far as I know) unless i can use this to wait?

Comment: Maybe you can use ``FileSystemWatcher.WaitForChanged Method`` [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.waitforchanged?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_FileSystemWatcher_WaitForChanged_System_IO_WatcherChangeTypes_)